# An algebraic Hamiltonian vector field with a finite number of periodic orbits (2)

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-equations, hamiltonian-mechanics, limit-cycles

Is there  a polynomial Hamiltonian $H:\mathbb{R}^{4}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that the number of nontrivial periodic orbits of the corresponding Hamiltonian vector field $X_{H}$ is finite but different from zero?

**Motivation:** The motivation comes from the fact that this can not be happen in Hamiltonians with $1$ degree of Freedom, i.e for Hamiltonians $H:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.

**Added September 7, 2020:** What about if we reduce the **polynomial**  condition to **Real analytic** condition?

This question is related to my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155590/an-algebraic-hamiltonian-vector-field-with-a-finite-number-of-periodic-orbits1)