# Dynamical analogue of Morse theory

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, morse-theory, hamiltonian-mechanics

Is there a Hamiltonian $H:\mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the  following  property:

For  two regular  values $a<b$  for  which $[a,b]$ consists of regular values, the  dynamics of $X_H$ on $H^{-1}(a)$ is  not  topological equivalent to the  dynamic of  $X_H$ on $H^{-1}(b)$?

Here $X_H$ is  the  hamiltonian vector  field associated  to the  Hamiltonian $H$.

The  motivation for this  question is  the  following post. The  answer  to the  following  post  would  be  negative if the  answer  to the  above  question is negative:

[An algebraic Hamiltonian vector field with a finite number of periodic orbits (2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210996/an-algebraic-hamiltonian-vector-field-with-a-finite-number-of-periodic-orbits-2)

Comment: Do you assume the Palais-Smale condition on the function $H$? (e.g., $H$ is coercive). Otherwise in your hypotheses already the sub-manifolds $H^{-1}(a)$ and  $H^{-1}(b)$ may well differ topologically (for instance: one is empty, the other is not, $H$ is bounded below but does not have a minimum)

Comment: In other words maybe you want “$a$ is a regular value” to be understood in a strong sense (“$\|\nabla H\|$ is bounded away from $0$ on $H^{-1}(a)$“).

Comment: @PietroMajer Thank you very much for your comment and the interesting point of Palais Smale condition. No I did not assume the Palais Smale  condition. But I remember a theorem in Hirsch book differential topology that every two non empty level set are diffeomorphic provided there is no critical value between a and b. He use normalized gradient vector field to prove this theorem.

Comment: So I wonder if every two regular level set as above have similar dynamics? If there would be a counter example then it would be interesting to prove it with extra assumption Palais Smale condition.

Comment: @PietroMajer Am I mistaken on diffeomorphicity of every two regular level set as above without PS condition? May be in Hirsch book we had the compactness of M which automatically implies the PS condition?

Comment: Yes, that is true for compact manifolds, or more generally, assuming PS condition, orherwise it may be false. Consider e.g. f(x):=exp(x) on R. No critical points, the level { f=-1} is empty, tge level {f=1} is not.

Comment: There is a "critical point at infinity" at the level c=0, that is a sequence with $f(x_n)\to c$, $df(x_n)\to0$, $x_n\to\infty$ (in the 1 pt compactification). It can be an obstruction to deformation just as a true critical point

Comment: @PietroMajer according to definition PS condition you mentioned above I think $exp$ satisfies this condition. On the other hand I think "exp" is not a counter example to the question in my last comment. Because in my last comment i search for an example of two non empty non diffeomorphic regular level set with values a and b such that [a b] consist of regular values. You said that in PS condition it is impossible but what about non PS condition

Comment: Actually $f(x)= \exp(x)$ on $\mathbb R$ does not satisfy PS, precisely at the level $c=0$, because there is e.g. the non compact sequence $x_n=-n$ such that $f'(x_n)\to0$ and $f(x_n)\to c$. Empty vs singleton is just the simplest pair of non diffeomorphic objects, but if we want two non-empty level sets, take $f(x)=xe^x$. The only critical level is the minimum $-1/e$ so $[-1/3, 1]$ consists of regular values, {f=1} is a singleton, {f=-1/3} is a doubleton.

Comment: For another example: take any smooth $f:M\to\mathbb R$ with two non empty non diffeomorphic regular level sets with values a and b. Then remove the critical set  $\text{crit}(f):=\{x\in M: df(x)=0\}$ from $M$: now $[a,b]$ consists of regular values of $g:=f$ restricted to $N:=M\setminus\text{crit}(f)$, since $g$ has no critical points. (And of course, if $\text{crit}(f)$ was non-empty, $g$ does not satisfy PS).

Comment: @PietroMajer yes I see. So it seems that a precise connected compact counter example is not straightforward. Yes?

Comment: What counterexample would you like exactly?

Comment: @PietroMajer  Befor I talk about the exact counterexample, I  would like to say that the mapping $exp$ satisfies an equivalent statment you  wrote in one of your previous comment: "the  norm of gradient is  far from zero on every level set" I think it is  not equivalent to PS condition.

Comment: By  counter example  I mean a  connected manifold  M with an interval of regular values [a,b] (no level set is  empty) but $H^{-1}(a)$ is not  diffeomorphic to $H^{-1} (b)$. I mean we emphasis on connected ness of M.  (We forget  compactness condition).  A modified question: a  connected manifold  and  a regular map without critical point which has two non diffeomorphic  non empty level set.  Thanks  again for  your  attention to my question.

Comment: Yes you are right of course, that was incorrect, sorry, one should say "$\|\nabla H\|$ is bounded away from $0$ on $H^{-1}([a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon])$ for some $\epsilon>0$" (this is "$a$ regular value and PS holds at level $a$")

Comment: Also, this way it is easy to build examples of smooth functions on $\mathbb R^n$ with no critical points and non homeomorphic level sets. Start from an $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ that has e.g. $\text{crit}(f)\subset \mathbb R^n\setminus\Omega$, $f^{-1}(a)\subset \Omega$, $f^{-1}(b)\subset \Omega$, and $\Omega$ is an open set diffeomorphic to  $\mathbb R^n$ via a differ $\phi:\mathbb R^n\to\Omega$. Then $g:=f\circ\phi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ has no critical points,  $g^{-1}(a)\sim  f^{-1}(a)$ and $g^{-1}(b)\sim  f^{-1}(b)$.

Comment: I did not recalculate this, but I think the following is true: even if you do not have compactness issues the dynamics can change drastically. You can have a hamiltonian on $R^4$ whose regular level set at $1$ is a sphere, where all orbits are closed, but at $2$ it is an ellipse with very few closed orbits.

Comment: @PietroMajer yes that is very good. Thank you

Comment: @ThomasRot I think you mean ellipsoid not ellipse. Moreover I think on sphere you have two singularities yes?(not possible qll solutions are closed orbit). I would appreciate if you wrote such a Hamiltonian

Comment: Here the sphere is $\mathbb S^3$, all solutions are great circles. His Hamiltonian could even be a strictly convex coercive function I think. Very nice

Comment: @PietroMajer  Yes I was mistaken since the energy level must have codimension 1. So 3 dimension. Could you please write the Hamiltonian you are talking about

Comment: Btw, suppose H satisfy $[J\nabla H,\nabla H]$ on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ w.r.to the standard  symokectic form. Then the Hamiltonian flow and the gradient flow of $H$ commute, and the your thesis holds. I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is again with the caveat that I have not done the calculations. Let $a>1$ be an irrational number. Let $H:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function such that

$
H(x,y,z,w)=(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)
$

when $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1$ and

$
H(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+aw^2
$

when $x^2+y^2+z^2+aw^2=2$. You can convince yourself that it is possible to find such a function without critical points in the region

$$
1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2\qquad \text{and}\qquad x^2+y^2+z^2+aw^2\leq 2
$$

(i.e. by interpolating the values in the region in between radially)

At the level set $H^{-1}(1)$ all orbits are closed because these are two uncoupled harmonic oscillators with the same period. At the level $H^{-1}(2)$ the motion is also described by two harmonic oscillators, but now with periods that are irrational with respect to each other. The only periodic orbits are those where one of the oscillators is not in motion. So there are two of them.

Comment: My  +1  and thanks  for  your  attention to my question and  your answer.  I  think some  thing is  missing.  It seems that  you actually use the following statement but I think it is  not true: "If $N$ is  codimension one submanifold and  $H_1$ and  $H_2$ are constant  on $N$ then the  two  Hamiltonian flow  are the same  on $N$" . This  is  not true  for  example put $N=$ unit  circle in the plane, $H_1\equiv 0$  and $H_2=x^2+y^2-1$ The first Hamiltonian  consist of   singularities and  the  second one  consist of a periodic orbit, two different  dynamic. Am  I missing some  thing?

Comment: I use the following fact: If $N$ is a regular level set of two different Hamiltonians $H_1$ and $H_2$, then the dynamics on $N_1$ with respect to $H_1$ is a rescaling of the dynamics of $H_2$ on $N$.

Comment: See for example the discussion in Weinstein's On the hypotheses of Rabinowitz' periodic orbit theorems