# A 1 dimensional foliation of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with few compact leaves

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Inspired by [An algebraic Hamiltonian vector field with a finite number of periodic orbits (2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210996/an-algebraic-hamiltonian-vector-field-with-a-finite-number-of-periodic-orbits-2) we  ask if there is  a  1 dimensional  analytic foliation of $\mathbb{R}^4$ which has at least 1 compact leaf and the number of  compact leaves of the  foliation is  finite?

**Note:** If there is no an analytic example  what about a smooth example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Conceptually, imagine a flow on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a single closed orbit on the unit circle in the plane $z=0$, while every other trajectory has an increasing z-coordinate. It's then easy to embed that flow in $\mathbb{R}^4$ to get the foliation you want.

More precisely, consider the vector field $$f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (-x_2, x_1, (1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2)^2 + x_3^2, x_4)$$

It has no zeros, because if the third coordinate is zero, then at least one of the first two coordinates is nonzero. So the flow given by $x'= f(x)$ defines a 1D foliation of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

And it has exactly one closed orbit (i.e. compact leaf), the circle of the form $(a, b, 0, 0)$ where $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. To see this, note that the 4th coordinate has to be zero in a closed orbit, and that the quantity $x_1^2 + x_2^2$ is constant on flow trajectories.

Comment: Thank you  and  my +1 for  your  answer. Does not it work for  every  arbitrary $x_3=c$?So we  have infinite number of  closed orbits. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Now that is very great  thank you

Comment: Great point, left out the key $x_3^2$ term, I just edited it to include this. Thank you!

Comment: I  wonder what is the  dynamics and  topological behavior of  codimension 1  distribution orthogonal to this  beautiful example? I  would  appreciate if  you send me  an email "alitghv@yahoo.com" for  more discussion.